# Parameterization for a flux integral

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, parametrization

Calculate $\int\int_S\nabla\times\textbf F \cdot d\textbf S$ where $S$ is defined by $z=e^{1-x^2-y^2}, z\ge1$ and $\textbf F = (-y,x,xyz)$. Orient $S$ so the normal is pointing downwards.

My attempt:
$\nabla\times\textbf F = (xz,-yz,2)$

I parameterize my surface: $\textbf R(x,y)=(x,y,e^{1-x^2-y^2}))$.

I know $d\textbf S=\textbf R_x\times \textbf R_y dxdy$. $\textbf R_x\times \textbf R_y = (2xe^{1-x^2-y^2}, 2ye^{1-x^2-y^2},1)$. I just take the negative of this vector so the normal faces downwards.

I then switched to cylindrical coordinates where $x=1cos\theta, y=1sin\theta, z=z$. Evaluating the integrand results in: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^e(2cos^2\theta - 2sin^2\theta+2)dzd\theta$$ I got e as an upper bound by looking at the surface. I'm not sure if this is right however. Setting $r=1$ does not seem right to me. I will provide a graphic of the surface. I think I could have just used the divergence theorem since it is a closed surface, but I want to be able to do the surface integral.[[image: Graphic of <span class=]$z=e^{1-x^2-y^2}$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TomFw.jpg)

Comment: Your change of coordinates after setting up the curl is wholly incorrect. You are doing an integral in $2$D now, there is no "cylindrical" coordinates. Not to mention the $z$ was already long gone since it was set to a function of $x$ and $y$ for the parameterization. It can not ans should not return. Just $r=r$ would have been fine. Then what are the bounds for $r$?

Comment: r would go from 0 to 1 then. So would this be an integral of the surface $x^2+y^2=1$? In that case would it be reasonable to use Stoke's theorem?

Comment: You could use Stokes' theorem. No this integral is not on a cylinder.

Comment: If I would be applying Stokes' theorem, wouldn't the closed curve just be the circle traced by the cylinder in the xy plane?

Comment: No, first of all there is no cylinder in this problem. Second of all, the curve $x^2+y^2=1$ does not happen in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Ok then I have to parameterize in terms of $\theta$ and $r$?. So would $r$ go from 0 to $e^{1-r}$? That would seem like an upper bound for z though instead of r. It might seem that this r goes on forever if z is exponentially decaying.

Comment: No your integral is fine as is, no reparametrization required. $r$ goes from $0$ to $1$

Comment: But this integral is easier with Stokes' theorem. You should consider doing that instead.

Comment: If I am parameterizing r, isn't it necessary to write the coordinate shift are $rcos\theta$ and so forth for y? In that case my integrand would be different.

Comment: You're using the word parametrization when that is not what you mean. When the dot product is complete there is no more vector stuff. At this point this is a change of variables to a new coordinate system, not a parametrization.

Comment: "a change of variables to a new coordinate system, not a parameterization". Oh ok you're right I was using the wrong definition. However I am still confused on why if we have z as $e^{1-x^2-y^2}$ and we switched to cylindrical coordinates, why we don't include $e^{1-r^2}$.

Comment: We do, but $r$ goes from $0$ to $1$

Comment: Alright, so my cross product instead will just look like $\textbf R_x\times \textbf R_y = (2xe^{1-r^2}, 2ye^{1-r^2},1)$? (where $x=rcos\theta$ and so on)